# Round Robin algorithm with people added and deleted

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Ok, in this codepen I already found a Round Robin tournament scheduling algorithm: https://codepen.io/Piconey/pen/mwPamw

```
var players = [
  {
    playerName: 'Person 1',
  },
  {
    playerName: 'Person 2',
  },
  {
    playerName: 'Person 3',
  },
  {
    playerName: 'Person 4',
  },
  {
    playerName: 'Person 5',
  },
  {
    playerName: 'Person 6',
  },
  {
    playerName: 'Person 7',
  },
  {
    playerName: 'Person 8',
  },
  {
    playerName: 'Person 9',
  },
  {
    playerName: 'Person 10',
  },
  {
    playerName: 'Person 11',
  },
  {
    playerName: 'Person 12',
  },
  {
    playerName: 'Person 13',
  },
  {
    playerName: 'Person 14',
  },
  {
    playerName: 'Person 15',
  },
  {
    playerName: 'Person 16',
  },
];

var numberOfRounds = players.length - 1;

function generateRounds() {
  for(i = 0; i < numberOfRounds; i++) {
    document.write('<h1 class="round">'+'Round ' + (i+1) + '</h1>');
    
    for (var j = 0; j < players.length / 2; j++) { 
      document.write('<div class="match">' + players[j].playerName + " - " + players[players.length - 1 - j].playerName +'</div>');
    }

    players.splice(1, 0, players[15]);
    players.pop();
  }
}

generateRounds();
```

I use it for a speeddating even where you can date with everyone.

My problem:
After every round new people can join the event or leave the event (if they get bored ;)

Note: The latecomers don't need to date everyone, because they already missed x rounds
Note 2: If a lot of people leave, it would be nice to limit the number of rounds so that people don't need to wait that long between dates

Comment: With n people, it takes n-1 rounds for everyone to have dated everyone else.  So with 16 people, it takes 15 rounds.  Lets say that a new person joins immediately after round 15.  Then everyone needs to date new person, and new person needs to date everyone, but there are no rounds left (are there?).  No matter who new person dates, 14 people are left doing nothing or repeating dates.  What do you want to have happen in this scenario?

Comment: Aah yes that's what I tried to explain but failed ;-)

Only one round is added if a new person joins. It will be a latecomber so it's probably more logically if it's after round 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: In your particular case. The speeddate already finished, so he's too late. But if he was one round earlier a new round should be added and he has 2 dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a bipartite matching problem like speed dating between separated sets of men and women, you can use a maximum flow algorithm.

Build graph in 4 layers:

1. Source node S
2. One node for each man
3. One node for each woman
4. Sink node T

- Fully connect layer 1 to 2 with edge capacity 1
- Fully connect layer 2 to 3 with edge capacity 1
- Fully connect layer 3 to 4 with edge capacity 1

When a person is added, add them as a new node in layer 2 or 3, and fully connect to adjacent layers as above.

When a person is removed, remove their nodes in layer 2 and 3 and all edges from their node.

At each round, use max flow algorithm to identify your pairings.  After round, set capacity of layer 2->layer 3 edges involved in the pairings to 0.  This will prevent the same two people from being matched again in subsequent rounds.

---

Heuristic:  You can modify the max flow algorithm to pair up the people with the either the fewest dates or the most rounds sat out first, so if an odd number of people exist, neither the newest person nor the same person is sitting out rounds.

Extensions: You can implement preferences to restrict the set of potential matches by filtering the set of edges added between layers 2 and 3.

Time: Roughly O(n^3) per round

Some javascript max flow package on github, never tried it so good luck:
https://github.com/orcaman/flownetwork

---

For an anyone to anyone matching problem, you must replace the max flow algorithm with the more complex Blossom algorithm.

Like max flow, this algorithm iteratively refines matches by finding augmenting paths then modifying its current set of matches.

The input for this algorithm is:

- Add a node for each person
- Fully connect all nodes

As in the bipartite case, at the end of each round, remove all edges corresponding to matches in previous rounds, preventing the same two people from being matched.

When a new person joins, add a node and fully connect them to other people.

When a person leaves, remove their node and all connected edges.

The Blossom algorithm is better described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm

A quick search shows several javascript implementations of this algorithm, your mileage may vary.

- [Matching Algorithm in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706201/matching-algorithm-in-javascript)
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/edmonds-blossom

Comment: Oh wow, that sounds complex (I already lost you with the mention of Source node S). Maybe I should forget about it and keep it simple...

Comment: Hahaha :D  Yeah it was a bit overkill!  How about: Line up 8 tables with chairs on either end, split groups into men and women, every round men shift one to the left (with wraparound).  For someone to join they have to join an empty seat.  If two people leave as a group, skip their table.  If one person leaves, hope someone joins :D

Comment: Hi @dhakim, awesome response, thank you. Do you think we can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-graph-algorithms#find-the-maxflow-mincut-using-ford-fulkerson-algorithm for achieving this? And if yes can you give a usage example? I am struggling extracting the pairs after each round.

Comment: @David'G' Ford Fulkerson should work yeah.  I've never used the package though.  The library should be able to output a graph that has the max flow assigned.  You then just examine the edges that it assigned flow to, those edges that cross between people and have assigned flow are the pairings that it chose.  You remove those pairings from your starting graph before the next round, preventing them from being matched again in future rounds.

Comment: @dhakim I managed to do it, but I have duplication problems.

The algorithm returns both sides of the pair. Example: if the following elements are used: `A, B, C, D` I get the `[[A, B], [B, A], [C, D], [D, C]]` pairs instead of just `[[A, B], [C, D]]`.

Currently I am manually filtering the results to remove the duplicates, but I ran into issues when using 6 participants. 1 participant have 2 different pairs. Example: for `A, B, C, D, E & F` I receive `[[A, B], [C, D], [B, E], [E, A], [D, F], [F, C]]`. As you can see, `A` is used in 2 different pairs. Any idea on how can I set the edges?

Comment: Max flow will limit the flow through each edge.  If the edge from source to A is limited to flow 1, no more than 1 flow can exit from A.  How much flow is assigned to the edges [A,B] and [A,E]?  How much flow is assigned to the edge [S, A]?  I'd guess one of the edges is just set wrong.

Comment: @DavidG Oh also make sure the max flow algorithm is set to use integer flows.  Otherwise it could do something stupid like split flow half and half across edges.

Comment: @dhakim I am using integer flows. Beside this, I've used your indications and all edges have a capacity of `1`. When the round ends I set the capacity to `0`.

`[A,B]` and `[E,A]` have a capacity of `1`.  `[S,A]` have a capacity of `1`. I have double checked.

What I can assume is that the problem is that I have 2 layers and maybe they are set wrong. In a sense that, in the first layer `A` is `1`, `B` is `2` etc. and to create the second layer `A` is `7`, `B` is `8` etc. And the algorithm doesn’t know that 1 & 7 are the same and that's why the duplication.

Comment: Is there any other way to create the layers instead of creating more nodes?

Comment: @DavidG Hah, whoops!  I think my construction is wrong!  This might be the construction for matching men and women.  If you put all men in layer 2 and all the women in layer 3, it should work for a speed dating system, but not the everyone to everyone tournament.  Let me think a bit and update the answer.

Comment: @dhakim That will be amazing!! Here it is a quick CodeSandbox example to demonstrate what I am doing now, maybe it will help you: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-water-de39m?file=/src/index.js . In my actual code I use generators for each round, helpers etc. If you need, I can even provide the full source code, but I think you'll get the idea :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233676/discussion-between-dhakim-and-david-g).